# If my opponent casts a spell that exiles a card with flashback from my graveyard, can I play it in response to their spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say my opponent casts [Purify the Grave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=226884) on my [Rally The Peasants](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=237361) in my graveyard. If I have enough mana available, can I cast the Rally the Peasants in response to their trying to exile it?

Comment: By Spider Spawning you meant Rally the Peasants, right? (I assume you realized Spider Spawning wasn't an instant.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can cast an instant whenever you have priority. All spells give all players the chance to respond to them, before they resolve. [Mtg Rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20120201.pdf):

> 116.1a A player may cast an **instant spell** any time he or she has **priority**. A player may cast a noninstant spell during his or her main phase any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty.
>
> 116.3d If a player has priority and chooses not to take any actions, that player **passes**. If any mana is in that player’s mana pool, he or she announces what mana is there. Then the next player in turn order receives priority.
>
> 116.4. If **all players pass** in succession (that is, if all players pass without taking any actions in between passing), the **spell or ability on top of the stack resolves** or, if the stack is empty, the phase or step ends.
>
> 702.32a Flashback appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents two static abilities: one that functions while the card is in a player’s graveyard and the other that functions while the card is on the stack. “**Flashback [cost]” means “You may cast this card from your graveyard by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost**” and “If the flashback cost was paid, exile this card instead of putting it anywhere else any time it would leave the stack.” Casting a spell using its flashback ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2e–g.

Comment: So if you really must remove that card from the Graveyard *now* without fear of reprisal, load up on [Extirpate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=126804)s. ;)

Comment: @ghoppe, technically you still have the ability to respond. It is just unlikely that you will have much of a response to make (only special actions like **Morph**, etc)